# How can I edit the code I messed up so badly I crashed my own website?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, crash, syntax-error

I tried editing the function.php file in my Wordpress theme.

Somehow I messed up and have a T_STRING error problem.  So, I looked it up, and find I need to add a double " speech mark on line 64.

BUT, now the site is crashed.  If I try to go in to do the edit I just get an error message telling me there's a  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /mysite/wp-content/themes/sahifa/functions/theme-functions.php on line 64

I mean, I don't get into the dashboard AT ALL, just this error message.

So how can I get in to fix, please???

Comment: You have a local copy, right? Simply upload the file via FTP. Done.

Comment: ah, thanks, I realised I had a copy on the dreamhost server..... so I could roll back.. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ftp into your site and edit the file manually